# How to handle unexpected asynchronous exceptions with runZonedGuarded?

Tags: flutter

I follow examples in [runZonedGuarded function](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/runZonedGuarded.html)  to setup reporting of unhandled async exceptions.

It works, but every output in console now prints twice:

```
sso: started silent sign-in
sso: started silent sign-in
sso: no user stored
sso: no user stored
async error
async error
```

Why it is and how can I fix it?

The code:

```
runZonedGuarded(
    () => runApp(MyApp(config)),
    (error, stackTrace) => print('async error'),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter for `runZonedGuarded` should be async function, not sync.
I added word 'async' and if fixed the issue:

```
runZonedGuarded(
    () async => runApp(MyApp(config)),
    (error, stackTrace) => print('async error'),
);
```